# How to initialize a GDuration (org.apache.xmlbeans.GDuration) object with some value?

Tags: java, xml, duration

I am trying to use the GDuration (org.apache.xmlbeans.GDuration) class to initiate an object like this,

```
static final GDuration gDuration = new GDuration(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, null);
```

to represent **15 minutes (PT15M)**, but is not working.

The error says, initialize problem. I haven't working with GDuration before and couldn't find any example so far.

Anyone can give me an example so that I can initialize with some value say, 15 minutes or 10 seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t tried `GDuration` either. So this is a “paper” answer with a bit of guesswork in it. I think I have a couple of good guesses, though.

Number one, have we got any reason to assume that the constructor accepts a `null` fraction of second? My first attempt would be this:

```
static final GDuration gDuration
        = new GDuration(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

If we can’t get that to work, another thing to try would be the `GDuration(String)` constructor. I didn’t see it specified in the documentation which format the constructor accepts, but ISO 8601 is a good guess.

```
static final GDuration fifteenMinutes = new GDuration("PT15M");
static final GDuration tenSeconds = new GDuration("PT10S");
```

Try it out and please report back whether it works. If I’m completely off track, I’d like to have an opportunity to delete this answer.

### Links

- Documentation: [`GDuration`](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/GDuration.html)
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Looks like String constructor is working. I'm yet to check the BigDecimal.ZERO for fraction of second.